# Android TimePicker hour field disappears after orientation change

Tags: android

I am using a TimePicker under API 1.5 and when the orientation is changed on my device (a stock G1 running 1.6 - though NOT on the 1.5/1.6 emulator), the hour field goes blank. It still remembers the hour, it just doesn't show it. Is there any workaround for this?

The same problem was described by someone else here:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/b4288004021b876/de5899a2bb291ab5

Nothing helpful was forthcoming - can StackOverflow do better?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I have the same problem.  DialogPreference is the base class and all the answers seem to assume it's an Activity.  I can see I'm setting the hour, but it's blank until you press the + or -, then the value is remembered.

Comment: Hi @user405821, i found this behavior on my device that's run GingerBeard. However, running the same app on JellyBean device, it is not happened. I am extending DialogPreference and using TimePicker on my PreferenceActivity(on JellyBeans, PreferenceFragment). I can't solve this problem yet.

Comment: @user405821 I added an answer that's solved my problem and can solve yours too.

Answer (score 6):

Simply move invoking of methods TimePicker.setCurrentHour and TimePicker.setCurrentMinute to onResume method of your Activity.

Comment: This alone was not enough for me. Setting the hour to a different value and then the real value (in the onResume method) solved the issue.

Comment: I agree with Ralf, in the previous comment.  Just before I set the value to the real value, I set it to zero.  The noted change causes the value in the field to repaint appropriately.

Comment: Setting the value to zero and then to the real value usually works for me but not if the real value is 12:00 a.m. So I set the value to zero, then to six and then to real value. It seems that this works in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, overriding the onResume() method will sort this issue.

```
   @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        TimePicker tmp = (TimePicker) this.findViewById(R.id.yourTimePicker);
        tmp.setCurrentHour(7); // This will also set on rotate

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22824
No matter what you do you won't be able to fix the issue without destroying the Activity and recreating it when the rotate occurs.  In order to not enter an endless loop simple check to see if the savedInstanceState != null in the onCreate. Something like this will work:

```
if (savedInstanceState!=null){
    Intent myIntent = 
        new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CurrentClassName.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);  
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onSaveInstanceState()` for your activity, get the hour value out of the `TimePicker` and place it in the `Bundle`. In `onRestoreInstanceState()` for your activity, get the hour out of the `Bundle` and put it in the `TimePicker`.

`TimePicker` should handle that on its own, but this may work around the problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't change anything. Interestingly, when I debugged in to see what happens on this time "change," I saw that ultimately TimePicker calls (internally) `onTimeChanged()`, and the only listener I ever see set for that is NO_OP_CHANGE_LISTENER.

I also tried calling `invalidate()` on the TimePicker during `onResume()`. No luck.

It's as if there's a setting somewhere that specifies not to show the hour; because it's being redrawn (obviously), it paints the container for the number, it keeps the existing value; it simple doesn't show the number.

Answer (score 0):

I've lost a ton of sleep over this and just figured it out.  When you're using a DialogPreference you need to override the showDialog method and reset your currentHour and currentMinute there.  Like this:

```
@Override
protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
    super.showDialog(state);

    mBeginShiftTp.setCurrentHour(mBeginShiftTp.getCurrentHour());
    mBeginShiftTp.setCurrentMinute(mBeginShiftTp.getCurrentMinute());
    mEndShiftTp.setCurrentHour(mEndShiftTp.getCurrentHour());
    mEndShiftTp.setCurrentMinute(mEndShiftTp.getCurrentMinute());
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link that DanRoss provided, the issue is related to the picker not updating the hour if the hour has not changed. Regarding orientation changes, this behavior is faulty because the hour before the rotation will always equal the hour after the rotation.

For those using the `TimePickerDialog`, a way around this is to extend the default implementation and force it to update the hour by updating the time (setting hour and minute to equal 0 in my example) and **then** update the hour to be the actual hour.

It may be possible to build something similar using only the `TimePicker` control.

Here is a working example for the TimePickerDialog:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class TimePickerDialog extends android.app.TimePickerDialog
{
    private final String HOUR_KEY = "Hour";
    private final String MINUTE_KEY = "Minute";
    private int hourOfDay;
    private int minute;

    public TimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView)
    {
        super(context, callBack, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);

        this.hourOfDay = hourOfDay;
        this.minute = minute;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged (TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {
        super.onTimeChanged(view, hourOfDay, minute);

        this.hourOfDay = hourOfDay;
        this.minute = minute;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle onSaveInstanceState()
    {
        Bundle savedInstanceState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            savedInstanceState = new Bundle();
        }

        savedInstanceState.putInt(HOUR_KEY, this.hourOfDay);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(MINUTE_KEY, minute);

        return savedInstanceState;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // The code for updating the hour is currently not doing anything
        // if the hour has not changed.
        // Force it to update by setting it to zero first
        this.updateTime(0, 0);

        this.hourOfDay = savedInstanceState.getInt(HOUR_KEY);
        this.minute = savedInstanceState.getInt(MINUTE_KEY);

        // Now it will update
        this.updateTime(this.hourOfDay, this.minute);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug is related on Android Official Forum [Bug 5483](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5483). Well, and that discussion, they suggest a simple solution and it works for me. I added the attribute `android:onConfigurationChanges=orientation` on my activity on `AndroidManifest.xml`.

**Important: Depending of you activity(others widgets ...), it can have side effects**

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm a little late to the party, but seeing as this problem still exists, I feel it deserves an actual answer.

From what I've read elsewhere, the issue has to do with the individual number fields of the TimePicker all having exactly the same ID. The reason this is a problem is because when you rotate the screen, android closes all of your dialogs, reopens all of your dialogs usings the typical onCreateDialog -> onPrepareDialog, and then, most importantly, **after you have made your dialogs, it goes back through and restores what used to be there.** This means that no matter what you do beforehand, android is going to come in and break your TimePicker.

The answer, although not the prettiest option, is to come in after android and set it again.

Here's how I did it, I simply made my own TimePicker:

```
public class MyTimePicker extends TimePicker {

    public MyTimePicker(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public MyTimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public MyTimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private final static String B_MIN = "bMin";
    private final static String B_HOUR = "bHour";
    private final static String B_SUPER = "bSuper";

    // here's the first key, we're going to override how the TimePicker saves 
    // its state

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(B_SUPER, super.onSaveInstanceState());
        bundle.putInt(B_MIN, getCurrentMinute());
        bundle.putInt(B_HOUR, getCurrentHour());
        return bundle;
    }

    // this function gets called when we are restoring, but before android 
    // does its thing

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if (state instanceof Bundle) {
            final Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable(B_SUPER));

            // here it is, not the prettiest option, but it gets the job done
            // we simply wait 0.1 sec and then update the TimePicker
            // since all of this happens in the same thread, its guarenteed to
            // be after the android reset

            // also, this handler gets the HandlerLeak warning, I don't 
            // think this can leak though seeing as it's only called once 
            // with a 100 ms delay

            (new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    setCurrentMinute(bundle.getInt(B_MIN));
                    setCurrentHour(bundle.getInt(B_HOUR));
                }
            }).sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);

            return;
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }
}
```

And yes, the handler is necessary. If you simply run the setCurrent commands from onRestoreInstanceState android will simply override you.

Answer (score 0):

I see this problem was active earlyer but I solved problem and if someone has this problem this is solve: 
Everything doing in onResume(), first get value for hour, then set hour on timePicker to hour+1 and then set to hour. That's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Crazy solution that works:

- Run AsynTask in onResume()
- Sleep for 50msec
- Switch back to UI thread, using Activity.runOnUiThread()
- In UI thread set min/hour to 0
- Then set min/hour to your values

Here is a gist with the code, ready for copy-paste :)
https://gist.github.com/sorrro/9415702